# Extract the phrase containing "FAILED" without a parenthesis following it

Tags: awk, sed, grep

How to extract the phrase containing "FAILED" without a parenthesis ')' following it and also remove anything which has "Linux x86_64)" preceding it?
e.g.
in:

```
Chrome Headless 117.0.5938.132 (Linux x86_64): Executed 5 of 270[32m SUCCESS[39m (0 secs / 0.018 secs)
WARN: 'Spec 'zip combines one value of each' has no expectations.'
[1A[2KChrome Headless 117.0.5938.132 (Linux x86_64): Executed 6 of 270[32m SUCCESS[39m (0 secs / 0.021 secs)
[1A[2K[31mChrome Headless 117.0.5938.132 (Linux x86_64) interval should emit every second FAILED[39m
    Expected $[0].frame = 1007 to equal 1000.
    Expected $[1].frame = 2007 to equal 2000.
    Expected $[2].frame = 3007 to equal 3000.
    Expected $[3].frame = 4007 to equal 4000.
    Expected $[4].frame = 5007 to equal 5000.
    Expected $[5].frame = 5007 to equal 5000.
        at <Jasmine>
        at TestScheduler.assertDeepEqual (src/misc/test_scheduler.ts:4:20)
        at filter (node_modules/rxjs/dist/esm/internal/testing/TestScheduler.js:139:22)
        at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
        at TestScheduler.flush (node_modules/rxjs/dist/esm/internal/testing/TestScheduler.js:137:43)
Chrome Headless 117.0.5938.132 (Linux x86_64): Executed 7 of 270[31m (1 FAILED)[39m (0 secs / 0.027 secs)
```

Expected output:

```
interval should emit every second FAILED
```

I tried this, which worked. However, how to improve it? i.e. without piping the output to sed.

```
grep ' FAILED[^)]' in | sed -e 's#.*Linux x86_64)##' -e 's# ##'
```

Comment: Try `grep -oP "\h*\K[^)]*FAILED(?=[^()]*$)" file`

Comment: your "worked" code does not produce the "expected out" you show with the sample input you show

Comment: @ The fourth bird : your solution works! Please put your solution as the answer (not as only comment) so I can give you the proper credit.

Comment: @ jhnc :
My system is Linux Mint 20.3 .

grep --version
grep (GNU grep) 3.4

sed --version
sed (GNU sed) 4.7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have `gnu-grep`, and not literally taking `Linux x86_64)` into account but prevent matching the parenthesis at all, you could make chars other than `)` before FAILED, and then assert no more parenthesis after it:

```
grep -oP "\h*\K[^)]*FAILED(?=[^()]*$)" file
```

The pattern matches:

- `\h*\K` Match optional horizontal whitespace chars and the forget what is matched so far
- `[^)]*` Match optional characters other than `)`
- `FAILED` Match literally
- `(?=[^()]*$)` Positive lookahead to assert no more parenthesis until the end of the string

Output

```
interval should emit every second FAILED
```

Answer (score 4):

I think this might be what you're trying to do, using any sed:

```
$ sed -n 's/.*Linux x86_64) \(.*\) FAILED[^)].*/\1/p' file
interval should emit every second
```

Comment: @ Ed Morton, how to include "FAILED" at the end?

Comment: Move the capture group closing `\)` to immediately after `FAILED`.

Answer (score 3):

With GNU `awk` you could try following code. Written and tested with your shown samples only.

```
awk 'match($0,/.*Linux x86_64) (.*) FAILED[^)].*/,arr){print arr[1]}' Input_file`
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk` to perform both the matching and the filtering:

```
awk '/FAILED/ && !/\(Linux x86_64\)/ { sub(/.*FAILED /, ""); print }'
```

Answer (score 0):

using any awk:

```
awk '/FAILED/ {for (x=1;x<=NF;x++) {
        {if ($(x-1)~/x86_64/ && (x-1)>0) lnx=1} 
        {if (x==NF && $(x)~/FAILED/) {print mystr "FAILED"}}
        {if (lnx==1) {mystr=mystr $(x) FS}}
        }}
' input.txt
```